# Break isn't working on my switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case, swipe

This is my code

```
if (xPrev < touch.pageY) {
    $("#debug").text("down :: " + nav);
    xPrev = touch.pageY;
    switch(nav){
    case 1:
        $("#container").animate({top:0});
        nav --;
        break;
    case 2:
        $("#container").animate({top:-alto});
        nav --;
        break;
    }

} else if (xPrev > touch.pageY) {
    $("#debug").text("up :: " + nav);
    xPrev = touch.pageY;
    switch(nav){
    case 0:
        $("#container").animate({top:-alto});
        nav ++;
        break;
    case 1:
        $("#container").animate({top:-(alto*2)});
        nav ++;
        break;
    }
};
```

I'm trying to animate my div several pixels when swiping down then stop, then when swiping down again animate to the other position but when I swipe for the first time it goes straight to the second position. The same thing happens when swiping up.

Im trying to animate between three positions if you count the start position, the ifs are to determine whether you are swiping up or down and in what direction to animate the #container

I have this variables:

```
var alto = $(window).height();
var nav = 0;
var xPrev = 0;
```

Comment: `break` always works. You have some logic error in your code, though it's hard to know what from your description.

Comment: When `nav == 0`, the first `switch` won't do anything.

Comment: @Barmar xPrev is initially 0, so any touch.PageY will be larger than 0, and it will fall into the else if.

Comment: @Zack You have that backwards. If `xPrev == 0` and `touch.pageY == 10`, `xPrev < touch.pageY` will be true, so the first `if` will be executed.

Comment: @Barmar yep. whoops.

Comment: @Zack Im trying to animate between three positions if you count the start position, the ifs are to determine whether you are swiping up or down and in what direction to animate the #container

Comment: @Barmar Im trying to animate between three positions if you count the start position, the ifs are to determine whether you are swiping up or down and in what direction to animate the #container

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your mapping of the different values of `nav` does not match the position you're animating to. For clarity I would make it so that  `nav` also - like the `y` axis starts with 0 on top and increases as the object moves down. This way you have a clear mapping of the "model" (variable 'nav') and the "view" (the position #container). I am not entirely sure if you are talking about three or four different positions. The following code will animate the object between three different positions.

```
var up = xPrev < touch.pageY;
if( nav<2 && !up ) nav++;
if( nav>0 && up ) nav--;
xPrev = touch.pageY;
$("#container").animate({top:(nav-1)*alto});
```

Comment: Im trying to animate between three positions if you count the start position, the ifs are to determine whether you are swiping up or down and in what direction to animate the #container

Comment: Right. This is how I understood what you wanted to do. The code above should do just that: animate between three positions.